# Gradle Drools 6.2 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'

Tags: java, maven, gradle, drools

I'm trying to pull in Drools 6.2 using gradle and keep getting the following error. I read that it could be an issue with repos that have poms, but not jars, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Frankly I'm a bit stuck and don't know how to proceed here.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve org.kie:kie-api:6.2.0.Final.
  Required by:
      1:1:1
   > Could not resolve org.kie:kie-api:6.2.0.Final.
      > Could not parse POM http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/kie-api/6.2.0.Final/kie-api-6.2.0.Final.pom
         > Could not resolve org.kie:kie-api-parent:6.2.0.Final.
            > Could not resolve org.kie:kie-api-parent:6.2.0.Final.
               > Could not parse POM http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/kie-api-parent/6.2.0.Final/kie-api-parent-6.2.0.Final.pom
                  > Could not resolve org.kie:kie-parent-with-dependencies:6.2.0.Final.
                     > Could not resolve org.kie:kie-parent-with-dependencies:6.2.0.Final.
                        > Could not parse POM http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/kie-parent-with-dependencies/6.2.0.Final/kie-parent-with-dependencies-6.2.0.Final.pom
                           > Could not find org.jboss.dashboard-builder:dashboard-builder-bom:6.2.0.Final.
                             Searched in the following locations:
                                 http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/dashboard-builder/dashboard-builder-bom/6.2.0.Final/dashboard-builder-bom-6.2.0.Final.pom
                                 http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/dashboard-builder/dashboard-builder-bom/6.2.0.Final/dashboard-builder-bom-6.2.0.Final.jar
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

group = '1'
version = '1'

description = ""

repositories {
  maven {
    url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'
    artifactUrls 'http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss'
  }
}
ext {
 droolsVersion = '6.2.0.Final'
}
dependencies {
 compile "org.kie:kie-api:$droolsVersion"
 compile "org.drools:drools-core:$droolsVersion"
 compile "org.drools:drools-compiler:$droolsVersion"
}
```

I've also tried:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

## EDIT:

For future googlers, we determined that Drools is a very poor match for Gradle. We had to cobble together a number of hacks to keep it working, and ended up switching to Maven. As with all things, YMMV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to tell gradle to look at different locations you should write the repositories like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
    name 'central'
    url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'
    }
    maven {
    name 'jboss'
    url 'http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss'
    }
  }
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. I'm still not sure why `mavenCentral()` didn't... That was what the guides advised.

Comment: Because the mssing dependency does not exist in the maven central repo, it's only found in the jboss repo you added (just browse the url with your browser to chechk this out).

Comment: That makes sense. I'm pretty new to gradle, and the docs around getting Drools built are a bit sparse, so I'm cobbling things together with a lot of trial and error.